# Where can I find a list of trees in the world?

Tags: trees

I want to make an app for smartphones that list most common trees in the world.

Where can I find a list?

I would like to include if the tree is deciduous or perennial and geography/climatic location.

I can buy a book if it is complete, preferably with photos of tree leaves. If I had only the list I may find the rest of information on wikipedia or other sites.

Comment: I suggest the Audubon society books, Ideally you want something with a dichotomous key, like https://gobotany.nativeplanttrust.org/simple/ Note I believe that legally if you are using their images and information for a salable app from any source you need that sources permission.

Comment: @John Thanks! I did something similar for minerals and I wrote a site to use their images with the agreement of including advertising of their website in the application. I will ask the authors for permission if I use this site.

Comment: Are you aware that the leaves are not necessarily the only thing you need for identification - you also often (usually) need flowers, fruits, size, branching patterns, and bark colour and texture. For instance could you tell the difference between [bitternut hickory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carya_cordiformis#/media/File:Carya_cordiformis_leaf.jpg) and [pecan](https://www.wildflower.org/gallery/result.php?id_image=29415) on leaf alone? Hint - pecan is slightly curved.

Comment: @bob I will include in my guide that info if I find it. I think I will buy Audubon society books. I guess they include that info.

Comment: Possibly, but there are some 60,000 species of trees in the world, so you aren't likely to find that in a single source. The Audubon guides only cover North America, and even then will only cover most of the trees. Comprehensive guides are often called a "flora", but this will include all species, though usually divided into volumes of monocots, dicots, algae,  bryophytes etc. rather than trees and not-trees. Flora don't always have pictures.

Comment: @bob1 I may try to make a guide about North America trees, make other for british trees with John's sugested site and search something else for my country Spain. Thanks, 60.000 wow!